# Convert the string in 123, 234, 345 etc. format

Tags: php

I have a string like below

```
$string = "hi hello how are you ? hope you";
```

I need result in array like below

```
hi hello how
hello how are
how are you
are you hope
you hope you.
```

I tried something like below

```
$exp = explode(" ",$string);

foreach($exp as $lol)

{

//now i have no idea what to do..some 1 guide me please.

}
```

Comment: an ordinary `for` loop would be better. just print the next three elements of the array and increment the index. Done.

Comment: you also have to remove the "?" from resulting $exp array, and then  do a double loop, first loops over $exp items, second loop displays 3 elements starting at first counter. However... you might want to learn the programming language you are using a bit better before posting here. for loops are probably one of the most basic concepts there is in programming.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 You are right, edit improved. I think now the numbers reflects what is given in the textual description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this use the `array_shift` and run the loop two times.

**Note**: Read the comment in the answer as i explain there why i wrote it this way.

```
<?php

$string = "hi hello how are you hope you";

$exp = explode(" ",$string);

for ($i=0; $i<(count($exp)+3);$i++)//as you want to print three value in 
//each loop your loop should run three more time than 
//the number of element you got in your original array
{

    echo '<br/>';
    for($k=0;$k<3;$k++)
    {

         echo ' ';//added the space to see
        print_r($exp[$k]);//to see the result
    }
    $value=  array_shift($exp);//after printing the result remove the 
    //first element from the array. so this will remove the first elemenet after 
    //each result.
}
```

Your Result will look like this

```
hi hello how
hello how are
how are you
are you hope
you hope you
```

Answer (score 0):

This code sample give 2 levels .No of foreach is the no of words.

```
$vari = "hai hello how?";

$vari = str_replace("?", "", $vari);
$vars = explode(" ", $vari);
$varp = $vars;
foreach ($vars as $p_i=>$p_v){
    foreach($varp as $c_i=>$c_v){
        if($p_i!=$c_i){
            echo $p_v." ".$c_v."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
hai hello
hai how
hello hai
hello how
how hai
how hello
```

You can put foreach inside another foreach to get more words.